# Modify menu to work with onclick event

Tags: wordpress, onclick, navigation, hover, accordion

I am using flat theme in my wordpress website.

Trying to modify a menu feature...spent a lot of time in it..but no luck.

I am just trying to modify the menu in a way that the functionality it is providing with "ontouchstart" event I want to modify it for "onclick" event. Like when we hover the menu item, if is having sub-menu then sub menus opens up....as we hover any other item the first one closes and the sub menus of that item opens up...just like accordion effect. I like this...but I need this for "onclick" event.

I have modified the code for it but not able to get completely what I want.
My html is :

```
<div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
            <div class="col-lg-3" id="secondary">
                <header role="banner" class="site-header" id="masthead">

                    <button aria-label="Sidebar" data-toggle="offcanvas" class="btn btn-link hidden-lg toggle-sidebar" type="button"><i class="fa fa-gear"></i></button>
                    <button aria-label="Navigation Menu" class="btn btn-link hidden-lg toggle-navigation" type="button"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>

                    <nav role="navigation" class="navigation main-navigation mCustomScrollbar" id="site-navigation">

                        <ul class="nav-menu" id="menu-primary-menu">
                            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-4 current_page_item menu-item-29" id="menu-item-29"><a href="http://localhost/mi6/">Introduction</a></li>

                            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-31" id="menu-item-31"><a href="http://localhost/mi6/index.php/planning/">Planning</a>
                                <i class="fa fa-caret-right open"></i><ul class="sub-menu" style="display: block;">
                                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-34" id="menu-item-34"><a href="http://localhost/mi6/index.php/planning/pm-tools-evaluation/">PM Tools Evaluation-This is addition text is added to test link wrapping on long content</a>
                                        <i class="fa fa-caret-right open"></i><ul class="sub-menu" style="display: block;">
                                            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-35" id="menu-item-35"><a href="http://localhost/mi6/index.php/planning/pm-tools-evaluation/comparative-analysis/">Comparative Analysis</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-32" id="menu-item-32"><a href="http://localhost/mi6/index.php/planning/crm-tools-evaluation/">CRM tools Evaluation</a>
                                        <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i><ul class="sub-menu">
                                            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-33" id="menu-item-33"><a href="http://localhost/mi6/index.php/planning/crm-tools-evaluation/comparative-analysis/">Comparative Analysis</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>

                                </ul>                               

                            </li>
                        </ul>

                    </nav>


                </header>

            <div class="sidebar-offcanvas"></div>

        </div>



    </div>
```

And Js is :

```
function(a){
"use strict";
a(document).ready(function(){
        a(".toggle-sidebar").click(function(){
            a(".row-offcanvas").toggleClass("active")
        }),

        a(".toggle-navigation").click(function(){
            a(this).toggleClass("open").next("#site-navigation").slideToggle(300)
        }),

        a("#site-navigation .sub-menu, #site-navigation .children").before('<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>'),
        "onclick"in window?a("#site-navigation .menu-item-has-children .fa, #site-navigation .page_item_has_children .fa").click(function(){
            a(this).toggleClass("open").next("ul").slideToggle(300)
        }):

        a("#site-navigation .menu-item-has-children, #site-navigation .page_item_has_children").not(".current-menu-parent, .current_page_parent, .current_page_ancestor, .current-menu-ancestor").hover(function(){
            a(this).children(".fa").toggleClass("open").next("ul").stop(!0,!0).delay(200).slideDown()
        },
        function(){
            a(this).children(".fa").toggleClass("open").next("ul").stop(!0,!0).delay(500).slideUp()
        }
    )}
    )}
(jQuery);
```

From the above code, menus are opening up with "onclick" but when we click on another li which is having sub-menu then the it opens up but the previous li is not closing like this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/6augy27b/14/

I want this should work as accordion like when I click on one sub-menu it will open its children but when I click on another sub-menu the children of that menu should be open and other sub-menu will close.

Answer (score 0):

can you please try below code it works on fiddel :

```
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.toggle-sidebar').click(function() {
      $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
    });

    $('.toggle-navigation').click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('open').next('#site-navigation').slideToggle(300);
    });

    $('#site-navigation .sub-menu, #site-navigation .children').before('<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>');

    if(!!('ontouchstart' in window)){
      $('#site-navigation .menu-item-has-children, #site-navigation .page_item_has_children')
      .click(function() {
        $(this).children("fa").toggleClass('open').next('ul').slideToggle(300);
      });
    } else {
      $('#site-navigation .menu-item-has-children, #site-navigation .page_item_has_children')
      .not('.current-menu-parent, .current_page_parent, .current_page_ancestor, .current-menu-ancestor')
      .click(function() {
          $('#site-navigation ul.sub-menu').slideUp();
          $('#site-navigation .fa').removeClass('open');
        $(this).children('.fa').toggleClass('open');
        $(this).children('ul').stop(true, true).delay(200).slideToggle();

      });
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: thanks Mukesh, its working but only for one level... I need this for one more level

Comment: Just look at my html, it is having sub-menu for each 'li' of sub-menu...please check once